# Angular5 Php structure for project

Tags: php, mysql, angular

Good morning,

I wanted to ask you if it was a good idea to use Angular5 with a php backend to connect a database to mysql.
Is it something that can be done or is it a bad solution?

Comment: You should create a REST API in PHP for your SQL database. And communicate with it with the help of the HttpClient service provided by Angular.

Comment: Welcome to SO Accabala! Unfortunately this sort of question is mostly opinion based and not well suited to this format. SO is meant for specific programming problems in a Q&A format. I recommend asking on a forum or subreddit.